# Call Spring MicroService from gwt

Tags: spring, gwt, microservices

I have a GWT client which needs to call a Spring Boot MicroService. I think it can be similar to calling a rest web service, but is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: If your spring boot micro service is REST based service, if YES you can call similar to calling rest web service, we use RequestBuilder for calling our spring boot REST micro service

Comment: Can you qualify "better"? The point of the spring boot microservice is that practically anything can call it, it isn't specific to any one kind of technology, right?

Comment: @ColinAlworth I mean if there is any library which handles all the boilerplate code and provides some templates which makes it easy to call Spring Boot Microservice

Comment: If the service is a REST service with JSON over HTTP, I recommend https://resty-gwt.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `RequestBuilder` to call your API from the client side of your GWT app:

```
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder;

// ....

try {
    new RequestBuilder(
            RequestBuilder.GET, // GET, POST, etc.
            url                 // url of your microservice endpoint
    ).sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() { // replace null with your req body if needed
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request req, Response resp) {
            // Parse resp.getText() which is hopefully a JSON string
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Request res, Throwable throwable) {
            // handle errors
        }
    });
} catch (RequestException e) {
    // log, rethrow... the usual
}
```

Comment: [Related GWT docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests)